# How to pop current view controller (non modal) and go back to previous one?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, view, controller

I am trying to use a custom back button on my View Controller in Objective-C to pop the current view controller so that i can go back to previous controller.
All the controllers are just view controllers and are not modally presented.
How do I programmatically pop the current view controller (non modal) and go back to previous one?

Comment: How u come to new view controller, is it presenting or pushing?

Comment: I used push in story board.

Comment: The project was almost done. I forgot to add navigation controller. When i added it is just added to the first view controller. So i decided to use back button in all the screens.

Comment: U mean push segue? is that any answer is relevant to you?

Comment: ya dismissviewcontroller is relevant to me for popping up the current controller and going back to the previous.

Answer (score 21):

this will pop the top controller from navigation controller stack!

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and if you are not aware of UINavigationController and its uses then follow this link

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UINavigationController/

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `UINavigationController`.
This maintains a stack of your view controllers. You can modify your view stack by calling `pushViewController:animated` and `popViewController:animated`.

Initialize your instance of `UINavigationController` with a rootViewController (your first view controller), and then present your UINavigationController in some way, then all you need is to play around with your `UINavigationController` instance.

Answer (score 2):

if you are pushing the view controller use:

```
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

else if you are using a modal transition use:

```
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
          //Stuff after dismissing
        }];
```

Comment: it worked by using dismissviewcontroller. Actually i was using regular view controllers so it worked.

Comment: Outstanding work for me